# Excel VBA Compare value from two workbooks then copy data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a VBA script that compare column D on workbook1 with column A on workbook2.
If it is a match I would like data from workbook2 column G to be copied to woksbook1 column E.

I´ve found this script:

```
Sub UpdateW2()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, FR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Workbooks("Excel VBA Test.xlsm").Worksheets("Blad1")
Set w2 = Workbooks("Excel VBA Test Backbone.xlsx").Worksheets("Blad1")

For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FR <> 0 Then w1.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(, -3)
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It is simple and does almost what I want but into wrong worksheet.
I doesn´t manage to switch which worksheet to copy data too.
Any help would be most helpful.

Comment: I have the code in w1 right know and a button to execute in that workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you need? Think you were copying the wrong way round and your offset wasn't quite right.

```
Sub UpdateW2()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, FR As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Workbooks("Excel VBA Test.xlsm").Worksheets("Blad1")
Set w2 = Workbooks("Excel VBA Test Backbone.xlsx").Worksheets("Blad1")

For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
    If IsNumeric(FR) Then c.Offset(, 1).Value = w2.Range("G" & FR).Value
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds :)

Comment: @ShaiRado - I probably saw it before you, had two cracks at it.